# How can I avoid a PickleError with multiprocessing caused by an object not needed by child processes?

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm having an error when trying to use multiprocessing, that from reading other threads I think is related to some objects in python not being picklable. However, in all the instances of this error I've found online, people are trying to pass these objects as arguments in the function being used in multiprocessing. In my case, I only need this object to load the data I'm going to process. I've created a minimal example that looks like this:

```
import multiprocessing
from test import Foo

def test(x):
    return x**2
   
def load():
    foo = Foo(analysis_folder)
    del foo
    
load()
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
print(list(pool.map(test, range(10))))
```

You can see that I don't even return anything from the load function, and I even try to delete the foo object from memory. The test function being used in multiprocessing is only being called with ints. However, I still get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 17, in <module>
    print(list(pool.map(test, range(10))))
  File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 268, in map
    return self._map_async(func, iterable, mapstar, chunksize).get()
  File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 657, in get
    raise self._value
  File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/pool.py", line 431, in _handle_tasks
    put(task)
  File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/connection.py", line 206, in send
    self._send_bytes(_ForkingPickler.dumps(obj))
  File "/opt/tljh/user/lib/python3.7/multiprocessing/reduction.py", line 51, in dumps
    cls(buf, protocol).dump(obj)
_pickle.PicklingError: Can't pickle <function test at 0x7f2c368881e0>: attribute lookup test on __main__ failed
```

With the call to the load function commented out, everything works as expected:

```
[0, 1, 4, 9, 16, 25, 36, 49, 64, 81]
```

Is there any way I can prevent this from happening? I've tried adding `if __name__ == '__main__':` before the last 3 lines, but still get the error. I don't understand why calling the load() function suddenly makes test() not able to be pickled.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

```
def main():
    load()
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(8)
    print(list(pool.map(test, range(10))))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Although this is a nice practice at any time, it is particularly critical for multiprocessing.  Remember, that second process has to reload all of the modules in your first process.  When it reloads your main module, it's going to run all that code again.

**Edit with the REAL answer**

OK, I finally see the problem.  The problem is that you have a module called "test" and a function called "test".  When the file gets reloaded in the other module, `from test import foo` is trying to import something from your function.  This caused Python to explode.  Either change the module or change the function name.

Comment: I still get the error. I have even tried moving the import statement for Foo into the load() function.